# When do you add a new project for a nested namespace?

Tags: .net, project-management, namespaces

I have many projects that are named after namespaces types are under

[image]

When adding a new sub-namespace, how do you decide whether to 
• create a new folder in a project
 
-- or  --
• create a new project in a solution?

What are some of dis/advantages I should consider for each scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question you have to ask yourself is: do the two sections of code logically fit together as one deployment unit? If so, keep them in the same project. If not, separate them.

To be honest, I would *rarely* create a new project for the "nested" namespace - it just doesn't seem to work that way usually. In particular, think about whether you'd want to access the "nested" namespace from the "outer" one and vice versa - if they would reasonably reference each other, then they should be in the same project.

Comment: Nested namespace mostly likely access the parent namespace, but not vice versa.  Parent namespace will not be dependent on the nested one.
So e.g) "Project.Common.Util" might reference "Project.Common" but "Project.Common" will be oblivious of "Project.Common.Util"

Comment: @Sung: I dissagree for example System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader) is but one example. I also seen this doen where a lot of configuration classes might be pushed to a child namespace.

Comment: @Josh: Wouldn't that create a circular reference usually?

Comment: What Job says makes sense. There is an exception I can think of, though: when the function in the namespace becomes sufficiently large, or is even optional, it may warrant its own assembly and project.

Comment: @Sung Meister: There are a few examples of circular references in the framework. It's not exactly an ideal situation :(

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my 2 cents to this question, to expand Jon's answer with some "been there - done that" experience:

I did use, in several solutions, at least two projects named by namespace (well, sort of). For instance, working on MyApp solution, I'd have `MyApp.Web` and `MyApp.Web.Controls`.

Or: `MyApp.Service`, `MyApp.Core`, `MyApp.Core.Entities` and so on. Pretty well known naming convention, where the root namespace goes like `MyCompany.MyApp.Service etc...`

**Advantage**:
- found it very useful when working in a team, to highlight the dependencies between app modules. If your `Web.Controls` module (it's just an example, don't pick on it :) is shared across the web UI, you typically don't want app-specific code in your custom controls. Keeping the "child/nested" module separate (referenced by the main project) enforces this.
- at least thinking of it will potentially help you create a better project structure. Which namespace goes in a separate project and which doesn't? Answering the question alone is helpful enough.

**Disadvantage**:
- it's very easy to get "trigger happy" and create a hundred projects instead of making appropriate folders/namespaces.

That said, usually tend to create folders instead of separate projects, except for the case when it's really a "sub-module".

Comment: +1 Great stuff, Dan!  Thank you for sharing your experience with this problem.